# Apple Sign-in not working on iOS 14 device & Emulators

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios14, apple-sign-in

When I try to log in for the simulator in iOS 14, the loading spinner just spins forever. There is a thread for this on the Apple developer forums here but no solutions and no response from Apple. I can certainly test on the device, but testing on the simulator is obviously easier for iteration. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the iOS 13 simulators to test SIWA on the simulator or, as you already said, you can test on iOS 14 on a device.

I would also suggest that you send a bug report to Apple. The more bug reports they receive the more likely it is that they will fix it.

Comment: I already checked it on iOS 14 device, but it does not work.

Comment: I checked the Apple sign in in iPhone Xs device, but it does not work.

Comment: @slizr88 any solution for iOS 14? I'm currently downloading iOS 13 on my simulator